# tllocalmgr reports "command install is not defined". What does it mean?

Tags: errors, bash, command-line

When I run the command

```
$ tllocalmgr install nicecolors
Initializing ...
Error: command install is not defined
```

Why does tllocalmgr report that the command `install` is not defined? The syntax is clearly `tllocalmgr install <package>`.

Comment: Although it would be better if this question soon "only applies to old deprecated tllocalmgr/TeX live installations" (i.e. the program is changed to give more descriptive error message).

Comment: To clarify, just posting in case someone in the future search for this exact error message on e.g. Google (it makes sense to *search for an error message online* when you get one, right?). **The typo itself cannot be searched for but the *error message* is**, and this one probably isn't that uncommon.

Comment: And there are precedents e.g. [python - 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax' for no apparent reason - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237111/syntax-error-invalid-syntax-for-no-apparent-reason) (although this one is on SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `tllocalmgr` reports that error message when the package is not defined.

Which happens when you make a typo in the package name, in this case it's probably `ninecolors`.